# how to find whether callback of an asyncronus call is finished or not in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a method called Get and a call back method called X written in C# .I Have to return the _name from the Get method.But it is only possible to get the Actual value of the _name after the callback is finished.So i have to stop at the point of * until call back is finished. After that only i can return the _name .So i have to find whether the call back is finished or not.

How do i achieve a solution for above scenario? Can any one please suggest a solution for this

My methods are something like this

```
string _name ;

public string Get()
{
     //Some Statements
     //Asynchronous call to a method and its call back method is X


     *Want to stop here until the Call back is finished

     return _name ;
}

private void X (IAsyncResult iAsyncResult)
{
     //Call Endinvoke and get the result
     //assign the final result to global variable _name 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ManualResetEvent to signal completion.

```
   string _name;
   ManualResetEvent _completed = new ManualResetEvent();

   public string Get()
   {
     //Some Statements
     _completed.Reset();
     //Asynchronous call to a method and its call back method is X


     //*Want to stop here until the Call back is finished
     _completed.WaitOne();

     return _name ;
   }

   private void X (IAsyncResult iAsyncResult)
   {
     //Call Endinvoke and get the result
     //assign the final result to global variable _name 
     _completed.Set();
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the wait handle from the  `IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle` and call WaitOne(). That will block until its complete.

```
  IAsyncResult result = Something.BeginWhatever();
  result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(); //Block until BeginWhatever completes
```

For a more complete example see the msdn article [Blocking Application Execution Using an AsyncWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228962.aspx)

Comment: Much better - I forgot about that one. Thx.

Comment: Ya..I tried this already it is waiting  until the callback start to execute.But not wait until it is finished